# Why is it neccessary to load firmware during boot?

Tags: boot, firmware

I've seen packages containing firmware for WiFi cards.

Also during Debian installation it asked me to load non-free firmware. Else my WiFi card won't work.

Linux seems to load this firmware during boot.

But how can firmware be loaded during boot?

I know routers and graphics cards having firmware. But it's stored in non-volatile memory (flash memory).

So how can it be necessary to load firmware during boot? It seems to be loaded into volatile memory (RAM). Why isn't it stored in flash memory as any other firmwares are?

Comment: Because the device uses volatile memory. And as for why at boot time: because it has to do it some time. And doing it before it is needed, seems like a good time. (All of this was in your question). Is your real question "why do hardware manufacturers use volatile memory?"

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is a price and speed issue.
To my knowledge, none-volatile memory is usually more expensive (for the same size) and slower than RAM.

Also, low budget routers usually don't have a HDD installed to load the firmware from and some drivers load the firmware into graphic cards when they are initialized.

Answer (score 1):

WiFi cards are *very* complex beasts (just look around for an overview of how that works, including roaming, cryptography, the protocols used for media access, and so on). Some of the job is negotiation when joining a network, that can very well be handled outside the card. Thus it is cheaper to implement a large fraction of the functionality in software running on the card or on the host, not in hardware. Given that, and relatively frequent changes (cryptography, protocol details, channels allowed by country, ...), it makes sense not to bake it into ROM on the card but load it on startup.